# SAPUI5 sap m table dyanmic columns and items bound in the view

Tags: sapui5

I have a odata service which provides an array of objects which are the column headers. How do I bind this data to my table columns.

I need to dynamically get all of the data of Columns and use this to set my sap m table columns, with the column description using the 'Fieldname' property.

[image: Columns data]

Tried to bind my view data (Columns) to the column, but that doesn't work like it would if you were applying it to the Table component.

```
<columns items="{view>/Columns}">
    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
        <Text text="{view>Fieldname}"/>
    </Column>
</columns>
```

Can this be done dynamically through the view?

Below is my current setup with the static columns solution.

```
    <!-- Production Plan Table -->
        <Table id="ProdPlanTable" items="{view>/MatchingOrders}" class="table">
            <!--Table Header Toolbar-->
            <headerToolbar>
                <Toolbar class="toolbarHeader sapUiMediumMarginTop">
                    <content>
                        <!-- Planner Group filter -->
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="{i18n>PlannerGroupHdr}"/>
                            <Select id="selectPG" items="{path: 'view>/FilterPlannerGroup', sorter: {path: 'Id'}}" change="onFilterSelect" selectedKey="{view>/FilterPlannerGroup/PlannerGroup}" width="200px">
                                <items>
                                    <core:ListItem text="{view>PlannerGroup}" key="{view>PlannerGroup}"/>
                                </items>
                            </Select>
                        </VBox>
                        <!-- Status filter -->
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="{i18n>StatusHdr}"/>
                            <Select id="selectSTA" items="{path: 'view>/FilterStatus', sorter: {path: 'Id'}}" change="onFilterSelect" selectedKey="{view>/FilterStatus/Status}" width="200px">
                                <items>
                                    <core:ListItem key="{view>Status}" text="{view>Status}"/>
                                </items>
                            </Select>
                        </VBox>
                        <!-- Required / Delivered UoM -->
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="{i18n>UoMHdr}"/>
                            <Select items="{view>/FilterUoM}" change="onUoMSelect" selectedKey="{view>/SelectedUoMId}" width="200px">
                                <items>
                                    <core:ListItem key="{view>UoMText}" text="{view>UoMText}"/>
                                </items>
                            </Select>
                        </VBox>
                        <!-- Toolbar Spacer -->
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <!-- Refresh button -->
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text=""/>
                            <Button text="{view>/LastRefreshTimeFormatted}" icon="sap-icon://refresh" type="Accept" press="refreshWithoutFilters"/>
                        </VBox>
                    </content>
                </Toolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <!-- Headers -->
            <!--<columns items="{view>/Columns}">-->
            <!--    <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">-->
            <!--        <Text text="{view>/Columns/Fieldname}"/>-->
            <!--    </Column>-->
            <columns>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>PlannerGroup}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>ProcessOrder}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>Info}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>Article}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="End">
                    <Text text="{i18n>OrderQty}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="End">
                    <Text text="{i18n>RequiredQty}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="End">
                    <Text text="{i18n>DeliveredQty}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>Status}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>StartDateTime}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>EndDateTime}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>LongText}"/>
                </Column>
            </columns>

            <!-- Items -->
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem type="Inactive">
                    <Text text="{view>PlannerGroup}"/>
                    <Text text="{view>ProcessOrder}"/>
                    <Text text="{view>GoodsRecipient}"/>
                    <ObjectIdentifier title="{view>Article}" text="{view>ArticleDescription}"/>
                    <ObjectNumber number="{path: 'view>RequiredQty', formatter: '.formatter.numberThousands'}" unit="{view>OrderUOM}"/>
                    <Text text="{path: 'view>SelectedUoMQty/RequiredQty', formatter: '.formatter.numberThousands'}"/>
                    <Text text="{path: 'view>SelectedUoMQty/DeliveredQty', formatter: '.formatter.numberThousands'}"/>
                    <Text text="{view>Status}"/>
                    <Text text="{path: 'view>StartDay', formatter: '.formatter.date'}, {path: 'view>StartTime', formatter: '.formatter.time'}"/>
                    <Text text="{path: 'view>EndDay', formatter: '.formatter.date'}, {path: 'view>EndTime', formatter: '.formatter.time'}"/>
                    <Button icon="{= ${view>LongTextExists} ? 'sap-icon://attachment-text-file' : 'sap-icon://add-document'}" type="{= ${view>LongTextExists} ? 'Emphasized' : 'Default'}" press="onOpenProductionNote"/>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>

        </Table>
```

Comment: So view>/Columns return that array of elements? It should correctly work to bind the Table as you did in the example. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot above is a console log of my view data 'Columns'. That's what I don't get either, why it doesn't work. For the table component I have bound another array of objects 'MatchingOrders' and this is the list item data, which works fine.